# Why does a useSelector result freeze my app when paired with a useEffect state update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reselect

EDIT: Question is invalid. There was a failure to properly use shallowEqual... no idea why array setter was caught and not string but I suppose it is immaterial.

This is a very peculiar bug:

```
const slice = useSelector(state => state.slice)

const [stringTest, setStringTest] = useState('')
const [arrayTest, setArrayTest] = useState([])

// APP FREEZES
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This never even fires')
    setArrayTest(['failure'])
}, [slice])

// BUT THIS WORKS
useEffect(() => {
    setStringTest('success')
}, [slice])

// AND THIS WORKS
useEffect(() => {
    setArrayTest(['success'])
}, [])
```

Why would my useSelector result, as a dependency, exclusively prohibit updating state as an array or object? Is there a workaround?

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure using setArrayTest(['failure']) does not fire a change in state.slice somewhere else in your component and therefore creates a loop?

Comment: It was actually a failed application of shallowEqual in the useSelector that I omitted in the repro. 
Still no idea why it affected array and not string, but there you have it

Comment: Glad that you solved!